# Using panels in place editor, how best to make "Save" button refresh the page after saving is complete?

Tags: panels

My code adds custom CSS to the page header based upon content in panels panes...using the in place editor, you can change a pane, then save the page, and not see your updated changes until you refresh the page.

Any simple way to make this page refresh after you click the "save" button?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Changes should appear right after you click save in the mini-panel edit form, and if they don't it might be a caching problem (especially if you click ctrl+f5). Try going to Conf > Performance, and there uncheck "Cache pages for anonymous users" and "Cache blocks", than flush all caches, and see what happens... If that doesn't help, try disabling External caching tool on server, and/or any advanced caching tool you might have installed, flush all caches and see what happens...

Comment: Thanks for the response. No caching is enabled, I think the only thing that isn't being updated is the drupal_add_css hook, which I'm using to add custom css to the page template based upon info in the panel pane. May sound funky but I think it's the cleanest solution to my problem.